# How to determine standard files when an EC2 instance gets launched

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to have a predefined httpd.conf file on every ec2 instance launched from elastic beanstalk autoscaling.

I'm running Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.8.1. With Apache/2.4.37.
From the docs. I got the following configured in my .elasticbeanstalk --> config.yml.

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf":
      user: root
      group: root
      mode: "000644"
      source: https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/.../httpd.conf
```

I was expecting that my custom httpd.conf file got launched when a new EC2 instance got launched from elastic beanstalk.

I have set the correct permissions for my s3 bucket. IAM rules on the S3 bucket is configured correct.

Comment: Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: do you need to restart apache at some point?

Comment: If you mean running the `service httpd restart`, then yes